# failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username error code LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, email

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. please help me

Comment: I have same error right now, but i didn't find any answer here! :(